# Zurb Foundation Sticky function not responding

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I am trying to implement the sticky function, as detailed here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html

I have added the required attributes as per the instructions. My HTML is:

```
<div class="columns medium-4 medium-push-8" data-sticky-container>
  <div class="sticky" data-sticky data-margin-top="0" >
    <!--content-->
   </div>
</div>
```

and I have ensured Zurb's JavaScript library is working.

When I view the page, the elements appear fine and in order, but the Sticky function just doesn't work.

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @Mediabeastnz no there's not

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. I know you mentioned that "Zurb's JavaScript library is working". But do you have a full set of Foundation libraries included or is it a custom build? You need to be sure that the following is included:

- foundation.sticky.js
- foundation.core.js
- foundation.util.triggers.js
- foundation.util.mediaQuery.js
- foundation-sticky mixin

Answer (score 0):

This snippet straight from the 6.3 docs works for me.

```
<div class="columns small-6 right" data-sticky-container>
  <div class="sticky" data-sticky data-margin-top="0">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="assets/img/generic/rectangle-3.jpg">
    <!-- This sticky element would stick to the window, with a marginTop of 0 -->
  </div>
</div>
```

If that doesn't work for you it's probably because you haven't included the correct javascript. Most of the time using the minified `foundation.min.js` saves a lot of issues as it includes all plugins.